# Meaning of “und” at the end of a sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure, conjunction

While reading *Ein Tunnel unter der Welt* by **Frederik Pohl** in dialogs (direct speech) I see sentences like:

- > Es war wie eine Explosion *und*.
- > Ich wußte es shon gestern *und*.
- > Ich ging in den Keller *und*.

Does it have the meaning similar to English *ok?, right?, yes?* (I use the question mark specifically here as I would expect an ascending intonation, like with German *was?* at the end of a sentence.) Or some other meaning (*und so weiter*)?

**UPDATE**: all these sentences end with a period in the book - I just omitted the angle quotes used to express a direct speech. Here is the excerpt to show these sentences with more context:

> »Oh!« rief sie, als ihr Mann ins Zimmer stürzte. »Liebling! Ich hatte einen schrecklichen Traum. Es war wie eine Explosion und.«
>
> »Schon wieder?« fragte Burckhardt, ohne besonderes Mitleid zu zeigen. »Mary, da stimmt was nicht. Ich wußte es schon gestern und.«

Comment: This strikes me as unusually weird. I haven’t read the book so I have no clue what the author may have intended. *Und* as a question particle (equivalent to *so?*) exists, but would require a question mark (and rising intonation). If it is not present, I have no clue.

Comment: Can you provide more context to the sentences? Also, are you sure that you got the punctuation correct (see also Jan’s comment), i.e., there is no comma before *und* and the sentences do not end on question marks?

Comment: Another possibility is - as you say the sentences occur in a dialog - that the person speaking is interrupted by another person. So the direct speech ends because the other person says something in a reaction to the first part of the sentence.

Comment: If what @jera assumes is true, I would expect ellipses, though.

Comment: I know that story - Actually, I only know the German translation - It would be interestong to know how those sentences look like in the English original. The abruptly ending sentences are apparently a stylistical means to drive the dialogue into some sort of hectic, breathlessness - He said more or wanted to say more, but the story needs to go on.

Comment: @tofro: yes, I think too it may be some sign of thrill/excitement. Something like `hmm` or `umm`? Since that's an electronic book, it might be the result of an incorrect OCR?

Comment: Mine is in print on paper and exactly looks as you describe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das ist lediglich schlechte Zeichensetzung in der Übersetzung.

> "Oh!" she gasped, as her husband came in the room. "Darling, I just had the most terrible dream! It was like an explosion and—"
>
> "Again?" Burckhardt asked, not very sympathetically. "Mary, something's funny! I knew there was something wrong all day yesterday and—"

http://www.gutenberg.org/files/31979/31979-h/31979-h.htm

Comment: Guter Fund. Wenn die Antwort jetzt noch auf englisch wäre und die reguläre Schreibung im Deutschen aufgreifen würde, wäre sie +1-würdig. :-) Im Moment eher als ergänzender Kommentar zu Pollizers Antwort geeignet.

Comment: @chirlu, deutsch zu antworten war bewusst, ich sehe keinen Grund, jemandem, der deutsche Bücher liest, auf Englisch zu antworten. Den Rest verstehe ich nicht. Meinst Du, ich hätte explizit schreiben sollen, dass es Gedankenstriche im Deutschen auch gibt?

Comment: Ich gebe mal zu bedenken, dass "Gedankenstriche ohne Gedanke" auch keine viel "richtigere" Zeichensetzung sind... Das ist nur eine andere Ausprägung künstlerischer Freiheit.

Comment: @tofro: Woher weißt du, dass es da keinen Gedanken gibt? Der Sprechende könnte im gezeigten Dialog sogar von so vielen Gedanken überflutet sein, dass er überfordert damit ist, einen auszuwählen und daher den Satz nicht schlüssig beendet. Alternativ könnte der Gedankenstrich auch für den Gedanken stehen, der zum nächsten gesprochenen Wort geworden wäre, wäre der Sprechende nicht durch den zweiten Charakter unterbrochen worden.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if Frederik Pohls sentences are meant to be incomplete direct speech, but if so, you write it either with a final ellipsis (*Auslassungspunkte*):

> »Ich ging in den Keller und ...«

Or with a final dash (*Gedankenstrich*):

> »Ich ging in den Keller und –«

Comment: In all cases there was a period at the end. »Es war wie eine Explosion und.«

Answer (score 0):

Without giving away too much of the plot of the story (I hope), this *stylistic* means has probably been chosen for two reasons:

1. You don't need to bee too detailed. Leave off what doesn't serve the main purpose (!)
2. Create some sort of hectic atmosphere where the characters are driven forward through the story and also create some lurking feel of "not right".

And no - neither the grammar nor the interpunction is right. Artistic liberty serves a purpose, here, I guess.

After the plot twist had come by I really thought "that fits".